# :s/nethack.wikia.com/nethackwiki.com/g ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There has been [a request](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10917/what-are-the-uses-of-engraving#comment-15097) to move all links to [nethack.wikia.com](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) to [nethackwiki.com](http://nethackwiki.com/), which I confirmed is hosted on the same server as the popular gameplay server [nethack.alt.org](http://nethack.alt.org/):

```
badp@delta:~$ dig nethack.alt.org | grep ANSWER --context 2 | tail -n 3
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nethack.alt.org.    3407    IN      CNAME   alt.org.
alt.org.            3407    IN      A       204.236.130.210
badp@delta:~$ dig nethackwiki.com | grep ANSWER --context 2 | tail -n 3
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nethackwiki.com.    3070    IN      A       204.236.130.210
```

Here's [the rationale](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Wikihack:Community_Portal#New_.22Wikia.22_aka_.22Oasis.22_skin:_Problems.2C_legal_restrictions.2C_and_tweaks).

We'd need to:

- check the transition doesn't break any link, and
- update the links.

Comment: What is the reason for the move?

Comment: @Fabian: see the linked discussion. Basically, it's the new layout and the social media stuff.

Comment: Let's hope StackExchange doesn't turn evil as well ;-)

Comment: @Fabian There _are_ other Q&A engines on the web and the content license is absolutely free, although nothing quite compares to this one yet.

Comment: Surprisingly, there aren't any of these links in comments, so no direct diamond intervention is necessary. There are only 3 posts remaining with such links (5352, 5100, and 430). I'm going to space the edits out.

Comment: @badp There are clones of SE whose *only* difference is being open-source. (Yes, I like necromancing old threads, just to annoy you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't all that many Nethack questions, so it was simple enough (even if long) to manually accomplish this task. Thanks for bringing this up!